# Auto is not allowed here for lambda class in header file

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm using c++14, auto is working fine on .cpp file, however when i try to create generic lambda in my class it generates error "Auto is not allowed here"

What did i do wrong?

Code:

```
class MyClass{
private:

    // Works
    std::function<void(MyClass&)> assign = [&](MyClass& other){
        //do something
    };

    // Does not work
    std::function<void(auto)> assign = [&](auto other){
        //do something
    };

    // Does not work
    auto assign = [&](auto other){
        //do something
    };
};
```

Comment: Reopened because the [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45632953/why-auto-is-not-allowed-as-function-argument) does not answer the question(s).

Comment: Which `auto` does the error message refer to? AFAIK, `auto` cannot be used for non-static member variables: https://godbolt.org/z/bnqz89.

Comment: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler also emits error when declared in cpp file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two attempts fail for different reasons. Let's look at the second one first:

```cpp
auto assign = [&](auto other){
    //do something
};
```

This *could* work in theory: the lambda expression has a definite type that could be deduced and used. However, as addressed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11302981/3233393) (for C++11 but still relevant), the language simply does not allow `auto` member variables, so that's that.

Your first attempt fails for a more design-related reason. Well, the immediate issue is that `void(auto)` is not a valid type (`auto` is a syntactic keyword with tailored semantics, not a type), but one *could* conceivably use some tag types to make `std::function<void(auto_t)>` a valid specialization.

The issue, however, is that `std::function` is a type-erasure tool: its goal is to take in and *conceal* a functionoid (such as your lambda), then call it on demand. By the time the call is made, the functionoid's type is not known anymore, much less its potential `operator()` template -- handling the general case would require instantiating that template at runtime for a yet-unknown argument type, which is not possible.

Bottom line: storing the lambda is conceptually valid but its type deduction is not supported, and type erasure is the wrong tool for the job since templates are involved. Your only solution is to create an explicit functor class, and use that as a member:

```cpp
class MyClass {
    struct {
        template <class T>
        void operator()(T other) const {
            // do something
        }
    } assign;
};
```

Bonus point: C++20 allows lambdas in unevaluated context and default-constructible lambdas, which means that the following insanity is now valid

```cpp
class MyClass {
    decltype([](auto other) {
        // do something
    }) assign;
};
```

Comment: Clear, concise, and answered all my questions! Thank you, its very interesting to see the rational where proposal for auto as member type is rejected. Different c++ versions have many changes and sometimes its confusing to see which one is which ._.

Answer (score 0):

These statements are perfectly ok on a different context / scope:

```
void myfunc() {
    auto lambda = []() { };     // works fine
}
```

But the *here* you refer is a class definition, where there can't be members without explicit types.

```
class MyClass {
     
   std::function<void(MyClass&)> assign = lambda;
   // works, because there exists now a variable assign,
   // of specific type, which is initialised from a lambda

   auto kOne = 1;  // fails for the same reason
};
```